# Problem in setting up Git in React Native app

Tags: react-native

I am installing React Native in Windows 8 (32 bit). I followed the following steps:

1. npm install -g create-react-native-app (Done)
2. create-react-native-app DemoApp

However, In step 2 there is an error:

```
git not found
```

I have also installed Git and setup variable. I have included `c:\program files\git`

Is it correct, or I have missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Can you run git from the commandline?
Type `git --version` in your commandline. If it complains about command not found, you need to make sure your PATH variable includes the git bin folder.

Type `echo %PATH%` in your commandline and see if the path to git is included there somewhere. (Usually C:\Program Files\Git\cmd or C:\Program Files\Git\bin)
If it's not included, you need to update your PATH environment variable by hand. First find out where git.exe is located exactly below your git installation path. Then update the PATH variable by appending another semicolon and the path you just found out (only the full path to the folder is needed)

See this thread on SuperUser for instructions on how to check and set the Environment variables on different operating systems:
https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them